# the session created in a page doesnt shares with other

Tags: php, html

when i create a session in php it still only in one page but doesnt get shared with others
the login page code:

```
<html lang="en" style='background-color: rgb(175, 192, 175);'>
    <head>
        <title>Kosumi - login</title>
        <link rel = "icon" href = "img\logo.png">
        
    </head>
    <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post" style="position:absolute;height: 200px; width: 200px;background-color: rgb(159, 181, 185);left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;right: 0; margin: auto;">
        <div style="height: 165px; width: 170px;left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;right: 0;margin:auto">
            <a href="index.php" style="font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 0px;">back</a>
            <p style="margin-top: 2px;">USERNAME</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" role='input'>
            <p>PASSWORD</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </div>
        <div style="height: 150px; width: 50px;left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;right: 0;margin:auto">
            <button style="right: 0;" id='login'>login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</html>
```

my login code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
echo $_SESSION['user'];
header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

and the logoff one:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}
session_destroy();
header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

i have noticed that the browser saves a "phpsessid" cookie but it doesnt seems to share with other pages. i tried to print the session id with `echo session_id();` but it is just blank.

Comment: Where do you try to output `session_id`? Do you start the session there? What's the purpose of `setcookie(session_name()`? Your login code is not secure in anyway, hopefully that is pseudo

Comment: yes it is just a test thing, i tried the session id output in index.php and the setcookie to clean cookies because it puts a short expiration time and deletes the cookies of session almost instantly.

Comment: What is the life of your sessions set to? You don't/shouldn't have that `setcookie` code. If the session is deleting the data likely is being removed from server as well so it won't exist.

Comment: the problem is that when i called `session_destroy();` and tried it along of other things i saw in other posts to how clear all session data when someone logoff it worked just to clear, but then i couldnt login again, the problem is sharing the session with other pages.

Comment: do all the other pages include `session_start();` at the top?

Comment: no, just the `login.inc.php` file

Comment: i tough that it shouldnt have session start when you said it, but seeing this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCo6JqGMi30 video i notice two things, it has `session_start();` in the other pages and it have the `exit();` in the end of the files, i did as how he did and now it is working perfectly, thank you for you answer though, if i understood it right i would have fixed this problem already. but yeah, `session_start();` is needed in the other pages aswell, i tough that doing once would work for every page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in my code is that i should have added `session_start();` in other pages that requires the session info too,like in the main page
[image: the user is being shown in the main page due to session start]

it seems like the page wont load the session info without that function.
as andrea meant when asked if i have `session_start();` in other pages. i am just answering because i know the solution now and nobody have written it in my post already, so other people can see easily how to solve this, thank you for who helped me with this.